# Lubuntu 12.04 & Steam

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, steam

I have a very old laptop *(Pentium M 1800 inside :D)*, and installed Lubuntu on it. 
Because of problems with the PAE kernel, I used LUbuntu 12.04 alternate install as described [here](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Ubuntu_Precise_installieren_auf_non-PAE_Systemen).
This worked out pretty well, so after that i installed `ubuntu-desktop` and had the glorious idea of installing Steam on it as well. I used the steam package provided by Ubuntu software center.

Right now after the installation, steam did update and start. Although it was full of graphic errors like missing buttons and a white background where steam usually is all black, I could even install a game. *(No, i do not want to play Counterstrike on this...)*, only one or another small-time killer games every so often)

But after a restart, steam now does not start anymore. Starting it via LXterm gets the following output:

```
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1363394289_client)
```

--- and then nothing happens. If this is an error message, I fail to see which error it describes.

I am totally new to Ubuntu (and linux on the whole), so if you have any idea on how to solve this i'd be really glad.

If not... well.. i'll get rid of steam and install MAME instead =) Might fit better for this old piece of hardware :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command in a terminal:

```
steam --restart
```

From the Steam-Support article [Refresh your Steam files](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3134-TIAL-4638)

> - You will see the following: Installing bootstrap
>     /home/[username]/.steam/steam/bootstrap.tar.xz
> - Reset complete!
> - Restart your computer.
> - This should remove and download new Steam files for your Steam client.

The article also says:

> This process will not affect your currently installed games.

You might still want to backup your data. Steam stores it at `~/.steam` and `~/.local/share/Steam`. The games are usually stored at `~/.local/share/Steam/SteamApps/common`

Comment: I would suggest you backup the folder .steam/ and .local/share/Steam for example in folder /SteamApps/common there are usually all game files. I would copy whole steam folder to external disk. That way you have it all backed up.

Comment: Thank you for edit @MadMike:) I'll try write my tips / answers clearer in future!